# Creating a RFC 1123 compliant date for HTTP header creation on the CLI

Tags: bash, http, date, rfc

I'm trying to create a HTTP 1/1 compliant date header using standard unix date(1) in order to post this to a RESTful server using curl or similar.

Any ideas what format to pass to date(1) to get this to be RFC 1123 compliant?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man date` for whatever version of date your OS provides and use the correct switches to print (see `man strftime`), from from left to right, with a space between each, first the date:

Day (Three letter abbreviation Mon-Tue-Wed...)  followed by a comma <kbd>,</kbd>,
the month (Three letter abbreviation Jan Feb Mar ...)
the year (4 digit notation 1970, 1971 ...)
and then time  `HH:MM:SS`.

And you might get something like `Fri, 20 May 2016 20:22:33 GMT`

Comment: went with `DATE=$(date -u +%a,\ %d\ %b\ %Y\ %H:%M:%S\ GMT)` in the end... not sure if these switches are right, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

`env TZ=GMT; date '+%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z'`

1. `%T` is equivalent to `%H:%M:%S`.
2. `%Z` is replaced by the time zone name.

The solution by @brad, `DATE=$(date -u +%a,\ %d\ %b\ %Y\ %H:%M:%S\ GMT)`, would be incorrect if the time zone setting of your system is not GMT. For example:

`env TZ=Asia/Taipei; date -u +%a,\ %d\ %b\ %Y\ %H:%M:%S\ GMT`

`%H:%M:%S` would be GMT+8 while the output is GMT, but should be CST.